# Creating infinite list out of ADT

Tags: haskell

In Haskell,

```
 > a = [1,1..]
```

creates an infinite list. Now I have the following

```
data Subunit = O | P deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And if I do

```
b :: [Subunit]                                                                   
b = take 6 [P,P..]
```

I get the following:

```
 parse error on input ‘]’
```

Why this is failing? What I need to add to be able to create an infinite list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nice catch! Indeed it errors out ...

```
> take 10 [P, P..]

<interactive>:6:16: parse error on input ‘]’
```

... but this does not

```
> take 10 [P, P ..]   -- one more space
[P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P]
```

Why the whitespace is significant? Because otherwise the syntax overlaps with module-prefixed names, which have the form `Module.name`. Here's how the operator `.` from `Prelude` is accessed, for instance.

```
> :t (Prelude..)
(Prelude..) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
> :t succ Prelude.. succ   -- infix use!
succ Prelude.. succ :: Enum c => c -> c
```

Hence, `P..` is `.` from module `P`, while `P ..` works fine in a list enumeration.

(Yes, this is an unfortunate quirk of the syntax ...)

Answer (score 3):

`[n,n'..]` is syntax sugar for [`enumFromThen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#enumFromThen) so you need your type be an instance of [`Enum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#Enum) type class.

<s>You also need a value, not a value constructor</s>:

```
\> data Subunit = O | P deriving (Eq, Show, Enum)
\> let a = P
\> take 6 [a,a..]
[P,P,P,P,P,P]
```

or (per @sepp2k comment):

```
\> take 6 [P,P ..]
   --         ^ space
[P,P,P,P,P,P]
```

Comment: "You also need a value, not a value constructor" `[P, P ..]` works just fine. A nullary value constructor *is* a value.

Comment: @sepp2k you are right. needs an extra space before `..`. without it `[P,P..]` errors.

Answer (score 3):

as an alternative to behzads answer you can do

```
b :: [Subunit]
b = take 6 $ repeat P
```

too - this one does not need the `Enum`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this line to generate infinite list of ADT.

```
infiniteSubunit = P:infiniteSubunit
```

Then you can use it as is.

```
b :: [Subunit]                                                                   
b = take 6 infiniteSubunit
```

Comment: May as well use `infiniteSubunit = fix (P:)` instead of doing the circularity yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As yet another alternative, to do what it looks like you want to do directly, use

```
b :: [Subunit]
b = replicate 6 P
```